# esp_now.h: No such file or directory

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, esp

```
Arduino: 1.8.19 (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, 4M (1M SPIFFS), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"
esp_now_testing:3:21: fatal error: esp_now.h: No such file or directory
 #include <esp_now.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
esp_now.h: No such file or directory
This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Couldnt compile for a node mcu esp8266 board. Have installed esp8266 library from boards manager [image]

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <esp_now.h>

// Variables for test data
int int_value;
float float_value;
bool bool_value = true;

// MAC Address of responder - edit as required
uint8_t broadcastAddress[] = {0x24, 0x6F, 0x28, 0x7A, 0xAE, 0x7C};

// Define a data structure
typedef struct struct_message {
 char a[32];
 int b;
 float c;
 bool d;
} struct_message;

// Create a structured object
struct_message myData;

// Peer info
esp_now_peer_info_t peerInfo;

// Callback function called when data is sent
void OnDataSent(const uint8_t *mac_addr, esp_now_send_status_t status) {
 Serial.print("\r\nLast Packet Send Status:\t");
 Serial.println(status == ESP_NOW_SEND_SUCCESS ? "Delivery Success" : "Delivery Fail");
}

void setup() {
 
 // Set up Serial Monitor
 Serial.begin(115200);

 // Set ESP32 as a Wi-Fi Station
 WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

 // Initilize ESP-NOW
 if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK) {
   Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
   return;
 }

 // Register the send callback
 esp_now_register_send_cb(OnDataSent);
 
 // Register peer
 memcpy(peerInfo.peer_addr, broadcastAddress, 6);
 peerInfo.channel = 0;  
 peerInfo.encrypt = false;
 
 // Add peer        
 if (esp_now_add_peer(&peerInfo) != ESP_OK){
   Serial.println("Failed to add peer");
   return;
 }
}

void loop() {

 // Create test data

 // Generate a random integer
 int_value = random(1,20);

 // Use integer to make a new float
 float_value = 1.3 * int_value;

 // Invert the boolean value
 bool_value = !bool_value;
 
 // Format structured data
 strcpy(myData.a, "Welcome");
 myData.b = int_value;
 myData.c = float_value;
 myData.d = bool_value;
 
 // Send message via ESP-NOW
 esp_err_t result = esp_now_send(broadcastAddress, (uint8_t *) &myData, sizeof(myData));
  
 if (result == ESP_OK) {
   Serial.println("Sending confirmed");
 }
 else {
   Serial.println("Sending error");
 }
 delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: Where did you get this code from? Although it does load `<ESP8266WiFi.h>`, the rest of this code seems to be for an ESP32 and not an ESP8266/NodeMCU.

Answer (score 0):

To use ESP-NOW with ESP8266 and Arduino IDE, you must use the "espnow.h" header file. In this case, the error codes change and only need to use int values ​​for success(0). esp_now_peer_info_t is not required to add peers. Here is the code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <espnow.h>

// Variables for test data
int int_value;
float float_value;
bool bool_value = true;

// MAC Address of responder - edit as required
uint8_t broadcastAddress[] = {0x24, 0x6F, 0x28, 0x7A, 0xAE, 0x7C};

// Define a data structure
typedef struct struct_message {
 char a[32];
 int b;
 float c;
 bool d;
} struct_message;

// Create a structured object
struct_message myData;

// Callback function called when data is sent
void OnDataSent(uint8_t *mac_addr, uint8_t status) {
 Serial.print("\r\nLast Packet Send Status:\t");
 Serial.println(status == 0 ? "Delivery Success" : "Delivery Fail");
}

void setup() {
 
 // Set up Serial Monitor
 Serial.begin(115200);

 // Set ESP32 as a Wi-Fi Station
 WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

 // Initilize ESP-NOW
 if (esp_now_init() != 0) {
   Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
   return;
 }

 // Register the send callback
 esp_now_register_send_cb(OnDataSent);
 
 // Add peer        
 if (esp_now_add_peer(broadcastAddress, ESP_NOW_ROLE_SLAVE, 0, NULL, 0) != 0){
   Serial.println("Failed to add peer");
   return;
 }
}

void loop() {

 // Create test data

 // Generate a random integer
 int_value = random(1,20);

 // Use integer to make a new float
 float_value = 1.3 * int_value;

 // Invert the boolean value
 bool_value = !bool_value;
 
 // Format structured data
 strcpy(myData.a, "Welcome");
 myData.b = int_value;
 myData.c = float_value;
 myData.d = bool_value;
 
 // Send message via ESP-NOW
 int result = esp_now_send(broadcastAddress, (uint8_t *) &myData, sizeof(myData));
  
 if (result == 0) {
   Serial.println("Sending confirmed");
 }
 else {
   Serial.println("Sending error");
 }
 delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: Your description of what needed to be changed is not complete. You have changed more than just the header file.